How to deal with a large spike of connections on server start?
I have a Java, Netty-based server that handles 40k keep-alive TLS (v1.2) connections. It works fine when connections are established with 30% CPU utilization (2 vCPU). However, when I do a new deployment and there are 40k connections active at the moment of restart, they all try to reconnect to the server ending up with 100% CPU utilization that never ends. The server restarts fine if there are < 20k active connections. So I ended up increasing the instance size 2 vCPU -> 4 vCPU which helped. However, I would like to save the server costs and think of my other options to somehow delay this spike of connection and spread them over time, so even 2 vCPU instances can handle it.
I read, that SO_BACKLOG option may help. However, it's not clear to me how to choose the exact value (the current one, netty uses is 4096). Should I set it to 128, 1024?
What are my options? (Except for SSL termination on other servers or adding Load balancers of course)
I already use the latest Netty version, epoll, and boringssl.
openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+9-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.3+9-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-80-generic x86_64)


There is no code in the question. [edit] your question to a [mre].

Look at what one time initialisation tasks are done, in case the spike is because of unnecessary duplication in those initial requests.

Reduce the SO_BACKLOG value. It causes more new connections to get dropped, so less are processed at the same time, thus reducing CPU consumption
